# QGIS save DAT,MAP,ID,TAB, Excel file in an existing geodatabase

Tags: qgis, mapinfo, import, esri-geodatabase, excel

I am using QGIS 3.10.3. I need to add some files (DAT,TAB,MAP,ID and Excel) into an existing geodatabase. As I am new to QGIS, how can I add those files into a geodatabase.

[image]

Comment: The files are mapinfo format. Its more about the geometry of your mapinfo file than simply saving into your geodatabase.  Are they compatible? ETL would be a good choice to do this work.

Comment: Yes, I do think they are compatible. My late colleague created the geodatabases using ArcGIS 10.8.2. He managed to add those type of files into his geodatabases. I use QGIS and need to add them. Never heard about ETL. I am not sure if I copy and paste these files into the geodatabase will solve the problem.

Comment: ArcGIS 10.8.2. comes with and ArcGIS Data Interoperability [ETL] https://www.safe.com/esri/arcgis-data-interoperability-extension/ (it just needs a license)

Comment: I am going to use ArcPro to convert from Mapinfo to ESRI format. Then I will be able to import these files to the geodatabase.

Comment: @GISNoh Is MapInfo symbology important for you? Or you want only to import your MapInfo layers into an Esri file geodatabase .gdb without retaining symbology?

Comment: No at all. I just want to import into an Esri file geodatabase.